# How to retrieve a list of users from VSTS REST API?

Tags: rest, api, azure-devops

Using the REST API, I want to get a list of users for an account, I had a look through the [reference](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/overview) but couldn't find a way.

Using a `GET` request I want to return:

- id (GUID)
- displayName (text)
- uniqueName (text)

for an account where `account` is https://{account}.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such REST API for now.

But I posted an user voice [Get users belongs to a VSTS account by REST API](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-visual-studio-team-services/suggestions/31553257-get-users-belongs-to-a-vsts-account-by-rest-api), you can vote and follow up.

Comment: I did solve this by going to Projects -> Teams -> TeamMembers and writing a function to get to the next level. Seems to get what I need.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear. But looking at the VSTS documentation, to retrieve accounts you can do curl based on the memberId

Here is the documentation for it.

https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/shared/accounts

Comment: I thought my question was very clear. A list of users for an account is what I want. The link you posted is a list of accounts. I did try it but I got an error `Invoke-RestMethod : The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.`